# Al usar la extensión PY2EXE el ejecutable que se genera ya incluye las librerías importadas dentro del script?

Tags: tkinter

Estoy realizando un script en el cual uso tkinter y Numpy, pero me surge la duda si al usar PY2EXE la librería NUMPY permanecerá cuando comparta el ejecutable creado por PY2EXE en otro PC donde no exista Python. La librería se mantiene o se debe crear una rutina para que cuando el ejecutable se esté instalando este descargue e instale la librería NUMPY.

Gracias por su ayuda

Comment: Has leído la documentación?

Comment: Hola Christian, por el momento no pero esperaba tener algo de información para evitar hacer el proceso de búsqueda tan extenso. Si conoces algo de información quedaría muy agradecido por tú ayuda.